# Minecraft Multi-World Spawns

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I am building a mini-game on this server and I am having a problem. At the moment the settings are set so when you die, you spawn at the main world's spawn. The server has the multiverse plug downloaded for the separate worlds. This mini-game does not need a plugin so far, so I don't have any way for the spawn to custom set. And I've tried to use command blocks but it doesn't seem to work. Do I need to download a separate plugin? If so what would that be? If not, what else can I do?

Comment: Command blocks can't teleport a player between dimensions (worlds).

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/Multiverse/Multiverse-Core/wiki/World-properties#respawn

See this link for how to set [for each world] where players respawn if they die in that world.

Comment: Can you bring the important parts of how to do this into your post? That way your answer will still be valid even if the article after the above link ever gets moved.